# Pageinit function causes repeated information

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

The following code retrieves information from the server and displays it on my page. It works fine when I call the method without pageinit function. When I call it with pageinit, I end up getting duplicate information x5.

For example I am supposed to retrieve and display the information:

```
Hello
```

I end up getting:

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

Please advice what is wrong. Tnks.

**Following code Works fine**

```
//Budget
    $.getJSON("example.com",function(data){
        var wrap = $("<div/>").attr('data-role', 'collapsible');
        //Create the h1 and the other elements appending them to bills List
        $("<h1/>",{
            text:"Budget Details"
        }).appendTo(wrap);
        $("<p/>",{
            text:"Bank Balance: \u00A3"+ data.bank
        }).appendTo(wrap);
        $("<p/>",{
            text:"Cash Balance: \u00A3"+ data.cash
        }).appendTo(wrap);
        $("<p/>",{
            text:"Daily Budget: \u00A3"+ data.daily_aim
        }).appendTo(wrap);
        $("<p/>",{
            text:"Daily Expense: \u00A3"+ data.spent_today
        }).appendTo(wrap);
        wrap.appendTo('#budgetList');
        $( "#budgetList" ).collapsibleset( "refresh" );
    })//end of budget page update
```

**Following code gives repeated information**

```
$(document).on("pageinit",function(){
    //Budget
    $.getJSON("http://example.com",function(data){
        var wrap = $("<div/>").attr('data-role', 'collapsible');
        //Create the h1 and the other elements appending them to bills List
        $("<h1/>",{
            text:"Budget Details"
        }).appendTo(wrap);
        $("<p/>",{
            text:"Bank Balance: \u00A3"+ data.bank
        }).appendTo(wrap);
        $("<p/>",{
            text:"Cash Balance: \u00A3"+ data.cash
        }).appendTo(wrap);
        $("<p/>",{
            text:"Daily Budget: \u00A3"+ data.daily_aim
        }).appendTo(wrap);
        $("<p/>",{
            text:"Daily Expense: \u00A3"+ data.spent_today
        }).appendTo(wrap);
        wrap.appendTo('#budgetList');
        $( "#budgetList" ).collapsibleset( "refresh" );
    })//end of budget page update
});
```

Comment: You need to bind `pageinit` to specific page(s). It fires one time per page, so if you leave it without specifying a page, it will fire whenever a page is initiated.

Comment: Binding to specific pages works and doesn't repeat the information. But that causes the display to appear funky without my collapsible set but guess that is another question. Do you want to answer this question for me to accept. Tnks.

Comment: as per your code, _collapsibleset_ should look fine as you're refreshing it. If it collapsibles inside are not styles, then use this `$( "#budgetList" ).collapsibleset( "refresh" ).enhanceWithin();`

Comment: Tried .enhanceWithin() still returns plain text w/o the collapsibleset.

Comment: weird, then `$( "#budgetList" ).collapsibleset();` should do the job.

Comment: $( "#budgetList" ).collapsibleset(); works!. Tnks.